# how do I update Node.js using cmd?

Tags: node.js, cmd, software-update

Update Node.js version using command prompt
My installed version is

> v14.15.1

LTS version is

> v14.17.1

**Using below two commands**

install npm

> npm install -g npm stable

install node using

> npm install -g node

using command also but the version is not updated

[image: Screenshot of command Prompt]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

its Works

```
1. sudo npm cache clean -f

2. sudo npm install -g n

3. sudo n stable
```

stabilize version installed

Answer (score 5):

You install `nvm` first (Node Version Manager):

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Then you say `nvm install <version>`.

And when you want to upgrade... it's as easy as `nvm install <version>`

And you can switch between Node versions:

```
nvm use <version>`
```

And by adding a `.nvmrc` file into the root of your project, you can wire up your shell to automatically switch to the version of Node.js specified in the `.nvmrc` file.

Comment: install LTS version  `14.17.1`  but installed current version 16.4.0

Comment: Just use the proper incantation if you want version 14 (`lts/fermium`): Just say `nvm install --lts=fermium`

Comment: Node.js v--lts=fermium.0.0 is only available in 32-bit.